# Can't fix broken package after upgrading to ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, 20.04

I just upgraded to 20.04 from 18.04 and end up with 26 number of the broken packages. I used multiple commands to resolve it. Here are my attempts

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 console-setup-linux : Depends: keyboard-configuration (= 1.194ubuntu3) but 1.178ubuntu2.9 is installed
 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 : Depends: gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 (>= 2.40.0) but 2.36.11-2 is installed
                  Depends: gir1.2-pango-1.0 (>= 1.41.0) but 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1 is installed
                  Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.24.7) but 3.22.30-1ubuntu4 is installed
 gnupg : Depends: gpgv (>= 2.2.19-3ubuntu2)
 grub-common : Depends: libefiboot1 (>= 37) but 34-1 is installed
               Depends: libefivar1 (>= 37) but 34-1 is installed
 grub2-common : Depends: libefiboot1 (>= 37) but 34-1 is installed
                Depends: libefivar1 (>= 37) but 34-1 is installed
 hplip : Depends: hplip-data (= 3.20.3+dfsg0-2) but 3.17.10+repack0-5 is installed
         Depends: libhpmud0 (= 3.20.3+dfsg0-2) but 3.17.10+repack0-5 is installed
         Depends: printer-driver-hpcups (= 3.20.3+dfsg0-2) but 3.17.10+repack0-5 is installed
         Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installed
 libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libapt-pkg-perl : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.30.0-9build1) but 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3 is installed
                   Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
                   Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 1.9~) but it is not installed
 libcairo-gobject-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libclone-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.64.2-1~fakesync1) but 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 is installed
                  Depends: libglib2.0-bin (= 2.64.2-1~fakesync1)
 libnet-ssleay-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libsane-hpaio : Depends: libhpmud0 (>= 3.20.3+dfsg0) but 3.17.10+repack0-5 is installed
 libxml-libxml-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libyaml-libyaml-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 perl : Depends: perl-base (= 5.30.0-9build1) but 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3 is installed
 perl-modules-5.30 : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.30.0-1) but 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3 is installed
 python3-apt : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 1.9.11~) but it is not installed
 python3-brlapi : Depends: libbrlapi0.7 but it is not installed
 python3-gi : Depends: libgirepository-1.0-1 (>= 1.62.0-4~) but 1.56.1-1 is installed
 python3-pil : Depends: libimagequant0 (>= 2.11.10) but it is not installed
 python3-protobuf : Depends: libprotobuf17 but it is not installed
 python3-uno : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 is installed or
                        libreoffice-core-nogui (= 1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3) but it is not installed
               Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installed
               Depends: libuno-cppu3 (>= 4.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
               Depends: libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installed
               Depends: libuno-sal3 (>= 5.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
               Depends: libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 (>= 3.6.0~beta) but it is not installed
               Depends: uno-libs-private but it is not installed
 python3-xapian : Depends: libxapian30 (>= 1.4.14~) but 1.4.5-1ubuntu0.1 is installed
 rhythmbox-plugins : Depends: librhythmbox-core10 (= 3.4.4-1ubuntu2) but 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 is installed
                     Depends: rhythmbox (= 3.4.4-1ubuntu2) but 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 is installed
                     Depends: gir1.2-rb-3.0 (= 3.4.4-1ubuntu2) but 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies


sudo apt-get autoremove

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 console-setup-linux : Depends: keyboard-configuration (= 1.194ubuntu3) but 1.178ubuntu2.9 is installed
 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 : Depends: gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 (>= 2.40.0) but 2.36.11-2 is installed
                  Depends: gir1.2-pango-1.0 (>= 1.41.0) but 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1 is installed
                  Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.24.7) but 3.22.30-1ubuntu4 is installed
 gnupg : Depends: gpgv (>= 2.2.19-3ubuntu2)
 grub-common : Depends: libefiboot1 (>= 37) but 34-1 is installed
               Depends: libefivar1 (>= 37) but 34-1 is installed
 grub2-common : Depends: libefiboot1 (>= 37) but 34-1 is installed
                Depends: libefivar1 (>= 37) but 34-1 is installed
 hplip : Depends: hplip-data (= 3.20.3+dfsg0-2) but 3.17.10+repack0-5 is installed
         Depends: libhpmud0 (= 3.20.3+dfsg0-2) but 3.17.10+repack0-5 is installed
         Depends: printer-driver-hpcups (= 3.20.3+dfsg0-2) but 3.17.10+repack0-5 is installed
         Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installed
 libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libapt-pkg-perl : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.30.0-9build1) but 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3 is installed
                   Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
                   Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 1.9~) but it is not installed
 libcairo-gobject-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libclone-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.64.2-1~fakesync1) but 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 is installed
                  Depends: libglib2.0-bin (= 2.64.2-1~fakesync1)
 libnet-ssleay-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libsane-hpaio : Depends: libhpmud0 (>= 3.20.3+dfsg0) but 3.17.10+repack0-5 is installed
 libxml-libxml-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libyaml-libyaml-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 perl : Depends: perl-base (= 5.30.0-9build1) but 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3 is installed
 perl-modules-5.30 : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.30.0-1) but 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3 is installed
 python3-apt : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 1.9.11~) but it is not installed
 python3-brlapi : Depends: libbrlapi0.7 but it is not installed
 python3-gi : Depends: libgirepository-1.0-1 (>= 1.62.0-4~) but 1.56.1-1 is installed
 python3-pil : Depends: libimagequant0 (>= 2.11.10) but it is not installed
 python3-protobuf : Depends: libprotobuf17 but it is not installed
 python3-uno : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 is installed or
                        libreoffice-core-nogui (= 1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3) but it is not installed
               Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installed
               Depends: libuno-cppu3 (>= 4.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
               Depends: libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installed
               Depends: libuno-sal3 (>= 5.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
               Depends: libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 (>= 3.6.0~beta) but it is not installed
               Depends: uno-libs-private but it is not installed
 python3-xapian : Depends: libxapian30 (>= 1.4.14~) but 1.4.5-1ubuntu0.1 is installed
 rhythmbox-plugins : Depends: librhythmbox-core10 (= 3.4.4-1ubuntu2) but 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 is installed
                     Depends: rhythmbox (= 3.4.4-1ubuntu2) but 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 is installed
                     Depends: gir1.2-rb-3.0 (= 3.4.4-1ubuntu2) but 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).



sudo apt-get install -f

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 console-setup-linux : Depends: keyboard-configuration (= 1.194ubuntu3) but 1.178ubuntu2.9 is installed
 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 : Depends: gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 (>= 2.40.0) but 2.36.11-2 is installed
                  Depends: gir1.2-pango-1.0 (>= 1.41.0) but 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1 is installed
                  Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.24.7) but 3.22.30-1ubuntu4 is installed
 gnupg : Depends: gpgv (>= 2.2.19-3ubuntu2)
 grub-common : Depends: libefiboot1 (>= 37) but 34-1 is installed
               Depends: libefivar1 (>= 37) but 34-1 is installed
 grub2-common : Depends: libefiboot1 (>= 37) but 34-1 is installed
                Depends: libefivar1 (>= 37) but 34-1 is installed
 hplip : Depends: hplip-data (= 3.20.3+dfsg0-2) but 3.17.10+repack0-5 is installed
         Depends: libhpmud0 (= 3.20.3+dfsg0-2) but 3.17.10+repack0-5 is installed
         Depends: printer-driver-hpcups (= 3.20.3+dfsg0-2) but 3.17.10+repack0-5 is installed
         Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installed
 libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libapt-pkg-perl : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.30.0-9build1) but 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3 is installed
                   Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
                   Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 1.9~) but it is not installed
 libcairo-gobject-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libclone-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.64.2-1~fakesync1) but 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 is installed
                  Depends: libglib2.0-bin (= 2.64.2-1~fakesync1)
 libnet-ssleay-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libsane-hpaio : Depends: libhpmud0 (>= 3.20.3+dfsg0) but 3.17.10+repack0-5 is installed
 libxml-libxml-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libyaml-libyaml-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 perl : Depends: perl-base (= 5.30.0-9build1) but 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3 is installed
 perl-modules-5.30 : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.30.0-1) but 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3 is installed
 python3-apt : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 1.9.11~) but it is not installed
 python3-brlapi : Depends: libbrlapi0.7 but it is not installed
 python3-gi : Depends: libgirepository-1.0-1 (>= 1.62.0-4~) but 1.56.1-1 is installed
 python3-pil : Depends: libimagequant0 (>= 2.11.10) but it is not installed
 python3-protobuf : Depends: libprotobuf17 but it is not installed
 python3-uno : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 is installed or
                        libreoffice-core-nogui (= 1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3) but it is not installed
               Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installed
               Depends: libuno-cppu3 (>= 4.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
               Depends: libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installed
               Depends: libuno-sal3 (>= 5.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
               Depends: libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 (>= 3.6.0~beta) but it is not installed
               Depends: uno-libs-private but it is not installed
 python3-xapian : Depends: libxapian30 (>= 1.4.14~) but 1.4.5-1ubuntu0.1 is installed
 rhythmbox-plugins : Depends: librhythmbox-core10 (= 3.4.4-1ubuntu2) but 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 is installed
                     Depends: rhythmbox (= 3.4.4-1ubuntu2) but 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 is installed
                     Depends: gir1.2-rb-3.0 (= 3.4.4-1ubuntu2) but 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies


sudo apt-get update –fix-missing
E: The update command takes no arguments
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal, and type:

```
sudo apt-get install -f && sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Update/upgrade packages using `aptitude`, it's more suited to figuring out dependency problems than `apt`:

```
sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude upgrade
```

Alternatively, you can open Synaptic package manager with the command `sudo synaptic`, and head to Edit --> Fix Broken Packages.  Then run the `aptitude` upgrade, and `dpkg --configure -a` again.